# NVIDIA X Server Display Configuration - I don't have any resolution! (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: nvidia, resolution, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have some problems with configuring the resolution of my screen in Ubuntu 13.04. The data of my hardware:

Acer Aspire V3-531G

Intel B970 processor (2.3GHz dual core)

NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M

My laptop has Optimus technology, hence I use Bumblebee for the nvidia driver to work properly. Bumblebee is working well, I can tun the `optirun` command. I start the NVIDIA Settings panel with the command:

```
optirun nvidia-settings -c :8
```

I saw this method in an other post in this site (I don't understand, what does it mean, but after so many troubles with my nVIDIA-card, I'm happy that it works).

As the Control Panel opens, and I try to change the screen resolution, I'm unable to do it, because the monitor isn't detected. I don't have the "Display" panel, hence I don't have the possibility to change the resolution. Here I link the image:
[http://imgur.com/h9zybeE&GDoCVPu](https://imgur.com/h9zybeE&GDoCVPu)

Hope you can fix this error!

Sincerelly:
Michael

Comment: I am having the same problem. Hopefully you can (partially) solve your problem by:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jockey/+bug/660443/comments/7

Comment: I found this extremely useful and almost feel your question is a duplicate of this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers. Using the ubuntu-drivers devices command I was able to find the "proper" nvidia to use :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading through [askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers) I came across this useful command.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended
```

This in fact will roll through the devices on your computer and suggest which drivers to install. I had the same issue as you and essentially installed the suggested driver and viola all was well again!